# Retrieve Google Calendar events using API v3 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, google-calendar-api

last year I was using the code found here http://gdata-javascript-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/calendar/simple_sample/simple_sample.html to retrieve all events from "now" of a public Google Calendar and then display the results in a webpage.
I modified that code to match my needs (see the code below).

Now, with API v3, the code doesn't work anymore and I'm not able to understand which lines of the code are deprecated and how to update them.
Could please someone help me with this code?

Thank you so much :-)

```html
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* Loads the Google data JavaScript client library */
google.load("gdata", "2.x");

function init() {
  // init the Google data JS client library with an error handler
  google.gdata.client.init(handleGDError);
  // load the code.google.com calendar
  loadMyCalendar();
}
/**
 * Loads the Google Event Calendar
 */
function loadMyCalendar() {
  loadCalendarByAddress('MY_ADDRESS@gmail.com'); /* address here
}

/**
 * Adds a leading zero to a single-digit number.  Used for displaying dates.
 */
function padNumber(num) {
  if (num <= 9) {
    return "0" + num;
  }
  return num;
}

/**
 * Determines the full calendarUrl based upon the calendarAddress
 * argument and calls loadCalendar with the calendarUrl value.
 *
 * @param {string} calendarAddress is the email-style address for the calendar
 */ 
function loadCalendarByAddress(calendarAddress) {
  var calendarUrl = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/' +
                    calendarAddress + 
                    '/public/full';
  loadCalendar(calendarUrl);
}

function loadCalendar(calendarUrl) {
  var service = new 
      google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('gdata-js-client-samples-simple');
  var query = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventQuery(calendarUrl);
  query.setOrderBy('starttime');
  query.setSortOrder('ascending');
  query.setFutureEvents(true);
  query.setSingleEvents(true);
  query.setMaxResults(100);
  service.getEventsFeed(query, listEvents, handleGDError);
}

    /**
 * Callback function for the Google data JS client library to call when an error
 * occurs during the retrieval of the feed. Details available depend partly
 * on the web browser, but this shows a few basic examples. In the case of
 * a privileged environment using ClientLogin authentication, there may also
 * be an e.type attribute in some cases.
 *
 * @param {Error} e is an instance of an Error 
 */
function handleGDError(e) {
  document.getElementById('jsSourceFinal').setAttribute('style', 
      'display:none');
  if (e instanceof Error) {
    /* alert with the error line number, file and message */
    alert('Error at line ' + e.lineNumber +
          ' in ' + e.fileName + '\n' +
          'Message: ' + e.message);
    /* if available, output HTTP error code and status text */
    if (e.cause) {
      var status = e.cause.status;
      var statusText = e.cause.statusText;
      alert('Root cause: HTTP error ' + status + ' with status text of: ' + 
            statusText);
    }
  } else {
    alert(e.toString());
  }
}

/**
 * Callback function for the Google data JS client library to call with a feed 
 * of events retrieved.
 *
 * Creates an unordered list of events in a human-readable form.  This list of
 * events is added into a div called 'events'.  The title for the calendar is
 * placed in a div called 'calendarTitle'
 *
 * @param {json} feedRoot is the root of the feed, containing all entries 
 */ 
function listEvents(feedRoot) {
  var entries = feedRoot.feed.getEntries();
  var eventDiv = document.getElementById('events');
  if (eventDiv.childNodes.length > 0) {
    eventDiv.removeChild(eventDiv.childNodes[0]);
                                        }   

  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  /* set the calendarTitle div with the name of the calendar */
  /*document.getElementById('calendarTitle').innerHTML = 
    "Calendar: " + feedRoot.feed.title.$t + "<br/><br/>";*/
  /* loop through each event in the feed */
 var len = entries.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i];
    /* contenuto e titolo sono invertiti */
    var cont = entry.getTitle().getText();
    var title = entry.getContent().getText();  /* get description notes */
   /* only events containing WORD_1 &/or WORD_2 & not containing '?' */
       if(cont.indexOf('?') == -1 && (cont.indexOf('WORD_1') > -1 || cont.indexOf('WORD_2') > -1)){
    var whereIs = entry.getLocations()[0].getValueString();
    var startDateTime = null;
    var startJSDate = null;
    var times = entry.getTimes();
    if (times.length > 0) {
      startDateTime = times[0].getStartTime();
      startJSDate = startDateTime.getDate();
    }
    var entryLinkHref = null;
    if (entry.getHtmlLink() != null) {
      entryLinkHref = entry.getHtmlLink().getHref();
    }
    var day = padNumber(startJSDate.getDate());
    var month = padNumber(startJSDate.getMonth() + 1);
    var dateString = day + "/" + month + "/" + startJSDate.getFullYear();
    if (title.indexOf(' - ') > -1) {
      cont = title.substring(0, title.indexOf(' - ')+3) + cont + " @ " + whereIs;
      title = title.substring(title.indexOf(' - ')+3);
    } else cont = "h_:_ - " + cont + " @ " + whereIs;
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    /* if we have a link to the event, create an 'a' element */
    if (entryLinkHref != null) {
      entryLink = document.createElement('a');
      entryLink.setAttribute('href', entryLinkHref);
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dateString + ' - '));
   entryLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
      li.appendChild(entryLink);
      
    } else {
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dateString + ' - ' + title));
    }     

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    
    var lo = document.createElement('lo');
    lo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cont));

 li.style.fontSize = "25px";
 lo.style.fontSize = "15px";


    /* append the list item onto the unordered list */
    ul.appendChild(li);
    ul.appendChild(lo);
    ul.appendChild(p);
    
  }
    eventDiv.appendChild(ul);
    }
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
</script>

<p id="events">LOADING CALENDAR . . . . . . . . . .</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: You can check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/migration for calendar migration guide.

Comment: Thank you, I solved :) I'll post the new code here, maybe could be useful for someone

Comment: FYI: looks like it's possible to bypass oAuth only with Google Apps for work.  [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) indicates a means to do it but points you to your Google Apps domain’s [Admin console](http://admin.google.com/) to complete the setup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SOLVED :-) here's the javascript code to access and show upcoming events of PUBLIC google Calendars, with Google Calendar API v3.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body bgcolor="black" text="white" link="#00ffff" vlink="green" alink="yellow">
<script>
    
var clientId = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID HERE'; //choose web app client Id, redirect URI and Javascript origin set to http://localhost
var apiKey = 'YOUR_APIKEY_HERE'; //choose public apiKey, any IP allowed (leave blank the allowed IP boxes in Google Dev Console)
var userEmail = "YOUR_ADDRESS@gmail.com"; //your calendar Id
var userTimeZone = "YOUR_TIME_ZONE_HERE"; //example "Rome" "Los_Angeles" ecc...
var maxRows = 10; //events to shown
var calName = "YOUR CALENDAR NAME"; //name of calendar (write what you want, doesn't matter)
    
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
    
//--------------------- Add a 0 to numbers
function padNum(num) {
    if (num <= 9) {
        return "0" + num;
    }
    return num;
}
//--------------------- end    
    
//--------------------- From 24h to Am/Pm
function AmPm(num) {
    if (num <= 12) { return "am " + num; }
    return "pm " + padNum(num - 12);
}
//--------------------- end    

//--------------------- num Month to String
function monthString(num) {
         if (num === "01") { return "JAN"; } 
    else if (num === "02") { return "FEB"; } 
    else if (num === "03") { return "MAR"; } 
    else if (num === "04") { return "APR"; } 
    else if (num === "05") { return "MAJ"; } 
    else if (num === "06") { return "JUN"; } 
    else if (num === "07") { return "JUL"; } 
    else if (num === "08") { return "AUG"; } 
    else if (num === "09") { return "SEP"; } 
    else if (num === "10") { return "OCT"; } 
    else if (num === "11") { return "NOV"; } 
    else if (num === "12") { return "DEC"; }
}
//--------------------- end

//--------------------- from num to day of week
function dayString(num){
         if (num == "1") { return "mon" }
    else if (num == "2") { return "tue" }
    else if (num == "3") { return "wed" }
    else if (num == "4") { return "thu" }
    else if (num == "5") { return "fri" }
    else if (num == "6") { return "sat" }
    else if (num == "0") { return "sun" }
}
//--------------------- end

//--------------------- client CALL
function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    checkAuth();
}
//--------------------- end

//--------------------- check Auth
function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}
//--------------------- end

//--------------------- handle result and make CALL
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
        makeApiCall();
    }
}
//--------------------- end

//--------------------- API CALL itself
function makeApiCall() {
    var today = new Date(); //today date
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId' : userEmail,
            'timeZone' : userTimeZone, 
            'singleEvents': true, 
            'timeMin': today.toISOString(), //gathers only events not happened yet
            'maxResults': maxRows, 
            'orderBy': 'startTime'});
    request.execute(function (resp) {
            for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                var item = resp.items[i];
                var classes = [];
                var allDay = item.start.date? true : false;
                var startDT = allDay ? item.start.date : item.start.dateTime;
                var dateTime = startDT.split("T"); //split date from time
                var date = dateTime[0].split("-"); //split yyyy mm dd
                var startYear = date[0];
                var startMonth = monthString(date[1]);
                var startDay = date[2];
                var startDateISO = new Date(startMonth + " " + startDay + ", " + startYear + " 00:00:00");
                var startDayWeek = dayString(startDateISO.getDay());
                if( allDay == true){ //change this to match your needs
                    var str = [
                    '<font size="4" face="courier">',
                    startDayWeek, ' ',
                    startMonth, ' ',
                    startDay, ' ',
                    startYear, '</font><font size="5" face="courier"> @ ', item.summary , '</font><br><br>'
                    ];
                }
                else{
                    var time = dateTime[1].split(":"); //split hh ss etc...
                    var startHour = AmPm(time[0]);
                    var startMin = time[1];
                    var str = [ //change this to match your needs
                        '<font size="4" face="courier">',
                        startDayWeek, ' ',
                        startMonth, ' ',
                        startDay, ' ',
                        startYear, ' - ',
                        startHour, ':', startMin, '</font><font size="5" face="courier"> @ ', item.summary , '</font><br><br>'
                        ];
                }
                li.innerHTML = str.join('');
                li.setAttribute('class', classes.join(' '));
                document.getElementById('events').appendChild(li);
            }
        document.getElementById('updated').innerHTML = "updated " + today;
        document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML = calName;
        });
    });
}
//--------------------- end
</script>
<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad'></script>
    <div id='content'>
    <h1 id='calendar' style="color:grey">LOADING . . . .</h1>
    <ul id='events'></ul>
    </div>
    <p id='updated' style="font-size:12; color:grey">updating . . . . .</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Saved me a HUGE headache. FYI for others, the two keys (clientId and apiKey) are generated from the 'enable apis' section of your project in the [google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com), and you're looking for the ["create credentials" dropdown](http://postimg.org/image/4fd9fe4d9/) to create an API key and an OAuth Client ID.

Comment: When I try to access, the `GET events? ...` gives me 404 Not Found. You can see the Net Tab view here - http://imgur.com/a/wqgju is there anyway to fix the issue and get events

Comment: I could solved the issue by making the Calendar Public

Comment: I'm surprised you don't have more up-votes on this, spent an hour messing around trying to get this to work and your answer solved it quickly! cheers.

Comment: Question on this though, is this decent practice, as clearly the keys would be exposed, I could hide this on a node server/etc. but perhaps since its public calendar this is fine?

Comment: A good-practice and reminder: to hide your API keys and Client ID into a `.env` file and also add the `.env` reference on your `.gitignore` file as to prevent these credentials leaking into code repositories (Github, etc...).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified, annotated, and updated script based on Max's original that makes use of Moment.js and JQuery. Read [the full blog post here](https://kb.zensoft.hu/javascript-to-display-a-public-google-calendar-as-a-list-on-your-website/) for details (including how to get your API key), or just replace YOUR_CALENDAR_ID and YOUR_API_KEY in the script below:

```
<script>
    /* This solution makes use of "simple access" to google, providing only an API Key.
    * This way we can only get access to public calendars. To access a private calendar,
    * we would need to use OAuth 2.0 access.
    *
    * "Simple" vs. "Authorized" access: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication
    * Examples of "simple" vs OAuth 2.0 access: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests
    *
    * We will make use of "Option 1: Load the API discovery document, then assemble the request."
    * as described in https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js
    */
    function printCalendar() {
        // The "Calendar ID" from your calendar settings page, "Calendar Integration" secion:
        var calendarId = 'YOUR_CALENDAR_ID@group.calendar.google.com';

        // 1. Create a project using google's wizzard: https://console.developers.google.com/start/api?id=calendar
        // 2. Create credentials:
        //    a) Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
        //    b) Create Credentials / API key
        //    c) Since your key will be called from any of your users' browsers, set "Application restrictions" to "None",
        //       leave "Website restrictions" blank; you may optionally set "API restrictions" to "Google Calendar API"
        var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
        // You can get a list of time zones from here: http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zonehelp
        var userTimeZone = "Europe/Budapest";

        // Initializes the client with the API key and the Translate API.
        gapi.client.init({
            'apiKey': apiKey,
            // Discovery docs docs: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/discovery
            'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'],
        }).then(function () {
            // Use Google's "apis-explorer" for research: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/
            // Events: list API docs: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list
            return gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                'calendarId': calendarId,
                'timeZone': userTimeZone,
                'singleEvents': true,
                'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(), //gathers only events not happened yet
                'maxResults': 20,
                'orderBy': 'startTime'
            });
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.result.items) {
                var calendarRows = ['<table class="wellness-calendar"><tbody>'];
                response.result.items.forEach(function(entry) {
                    var startsAt = moment(entry.start.dateTime).format("L") + ' ' + moment(entry.start.dateTime).format("LT");
                    var endsAt = moment(entry.end.dateTime).format("LT");
                    calendarRows.push(`<tr><td>${startsAt} - ${endsAt}</td><td>${entry.summary}</td></tr>`);
                });
                calendarRows.push('</tbody></table>');
                $('#wellness-calendar').html(calendarRows.join(""));
            }
        }, function (reason) {
            console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
    };

    // Loads the JavaScript client library and invokes `start` afterwards.
    gapi.load('client', printCalendar);
</script>
```

You will also need to include Moment.JS and the Google JS API somewhere in your page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment. BTW, you forgot to replace your apiKey with variable

Comment: True that! Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thank you for creating this! It helped me breeze through a project. For those who have to support IE11 and don't want to transpile ES6 > ES5, don't need jQuery and want a lighter weight version of MomentJS (Moment is 70kb gzipped, dayJS is 3kb gzipped), I created a gist with this in mind:

https://gist.github.com/adamjohnson/bf601ea10611a0a46566eb66060b332d