# Displaying events from a public Google Calendar using calendar API without OAuth2

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

Firstly, I understand there have been very similar questions to this, but mine is slightly more specific. Upon looking at the API, I saw there is a GUI way of testing queries on the [page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it) at the bottom. With most of the 'try it now' demos, it requires you to toggle OAuth on at the top, before it will return results, however with the event.list method, that is not required.

To check, I opened the same link in an incognito window, and happily returned event data from my Public Google Calendar.

My question is: is there a way to display these events (that seemingly don't **need** the authorization) that doesn't require a user to sign in, in JavaScript?

At the moment, my code looks as follows:

```js
var apiKey = 'my-api-key';
var clientId = 'my-client-id';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly';

//Handles authorization
//function called when javascript client library loads
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(aapiKey);
  window.setTimeOut(checkAuth,1);
}

function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true},
      handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    makeApiCall();
  } else {
  }
}


//called on button click, calls library authorize method
function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: scopes,
      immediate: false
    },
    handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

//request data
function makeApiCall() {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var d = new Date();
    d = d.toISOString();
    d = d.split(".")[0] + "Z";
    console.log(d, ' = date');
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'ed.prince5769@gmail.com',
      'timeMin': d,
      'orderBy': 'startTime',
      'singleEvents': 'true',
      'maxResults': 10
     });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      //function that calculates current date and only keeps values of 


      //Set the max number of items to display
      //loop over all results, appending summary and date to the list element
      for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
        console.log(resp.items[i].summary);
        console.log(resp.items[i].description);

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary));
        document.getElementById('events').appendChild(li);
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        //li.appendChild(br);
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.className = 'date';
        li.appendChild(p);

        var date = (resp.items[i].start.date);

        //Reverse format of the date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy to make  more readable
        date = date.split('-').reverse().join("-");

        //Present date in language format
        var date0 = date.split('-')[0];
        var date1 = date.split('-')[1];
        var date2 = date.split('-')[2]; 
        var dateEnding;

        if (date0.charAt(0) === '1') {
          dateEnding = 'th';
        } else {
          switch (date0.charAt(1)) {
            case '1':
              dateEnding = 'st';
              break;
            case '2':
              dateEnding = 'nd';
              break;
            case '3':
              dateEnding = 'rd';
              break;
            case '4':
              dateEnding = 'th';
              break;
            case '5': 
              dateEnding = 'th';
              break;
            case '6':
              dateEnding = 'th';
              break;
            case '7':
              dateEnding = 'th';
              break;
            case '8':
              dateEnding = 'th';
              break;
            case '9':
              dateEnding = 'th';
              break;
            case '0':
              dateEnding = 'th';
              break;
          }
        }
        if (date0.charAt(0) === '0') {
          date0 = date0.substring(1);
        }

        var month;

        switch (date1) {
          case '01':
            month = 'January';
            break;
          case '02':
            month = 'February';
            break;
          case '03':
            month = 'March';
            break;
          case '04':
            month = 'April';
            break;
          case '05':
            month = 'May';
            break;
          case '06':
            month = 'June';
            break;
          case '07':
            month = 'July';
            break;
          case '08':
            month = 'August';
            break;
          case '09':
            month = 'September';
            break;
          case '10':
            month = 'October';
            break;
          case '11':
            month = 'November';
            break;
          case '12':
            month = 'December';
            break;
        }

        date = date0 + dateEnding +  " " + month + " " + date2;
        console.log(date); 






        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date));
        p.style.color = '#AEAEAE'; 
        p.style.marginTop = '0';
        p.style.marginBottom = '0';
        p.style.fontSize = 'small';

        console.log(resp.items[i].start.date);
      }
    });
  });
}

//calculate unix timestamp from an input x
function calculateUnixTimestamp(x) {
  return Date.parse(x)/1000;
}

//make sure page is loaded before executing code
window.addEventListener('load', function() {  
  handleAuthClick();  
});
```

I know that the majority of this code will probably be useless for helping, but I thought I would include all just in case anything else in there may affect the solution.

Comment: You can only get/list the events of public google calendar without user authentication. This can be done using events.list(to list all the events), and events.get(to get particular event). check this link for sample code in java script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262674/retrieve-google-calendar-events-using-api-v3-in-javascript and https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js

Comment: looks like it's possible only with Google Apps for work.  [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) indicates a means to do it but points you to your Google Apps domain’s [Admin console](http://admin.google.com/) to complete the setup.