# Google calendar API v3 javascript format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-calendar-api

I'm utilizing the new Google calendar API to create a list of events on a website, and I'm having trouble formatting the output. I followed the tutorial at this link:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js

By following the tutorial I was able to get everything up and running quickly. I wanted to style the list of events for my website but I'm not sure how to format the output. In the tutorial I followed I used OAuth to give me a client ID instead of an API key. Right now in this tutorial the output of events is a solid block of text thats generated with `createTextNode()`.

Here is a portion from the tutorial above that prints the calendar events to the website:

```
     /**
   * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
   * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
   * appropriate message is printed.
   */
  function listUpcomingEvents() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 10,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var events = resp.items;
      appendPre('Upcoming events:');

      if (events.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var when = event.start.dateTime;
          if (!when) {
            when = event.start.date;
          }
          appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
      }

    });
  }

  /**
   * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
   * as its text node.
   *
   * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
   */
  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('output');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }
```

And the result is a list of events with the title of the event and the date in the ISO format.

QUESTION: How can you format this information so that the title of each event will be in a `h1` tag and the date/time will be in a `h2` tag instead of all of the output in one giant text node?

Also, I'm using a private calendar.

EDIT:
I found this repo
https://github.com/MilanKacurak/FormatGoogleCalendar
This looks exactly like the kind of formatting I'm looking for, but it only works for public calendars. Does anyone know if there is a way utilize something like this with a private calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more digging I was able to find a similar question and was able to use it to solve my problem.

In this link, the answer to this question helped solve my question.

[Retrieve Google Calendar events using API v3 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262674/retrieve-google-calendar-events-using-api-v3-in-javascript)

In this link it says it is for public calendars, but I was able to use it with my private calendar as well. I guess the biggest problem I was having was figuring out how to format the response from the api to include custom css class names and styles. If you know of a different/better answer please let me know.