# Retrieve single Calendar Event using API v3 in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I have modified the script found here [Retrieve Google Calendar events using API v3 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262674/retrieve-google-calendar-events-using-api-v3-in-javascript) to display a page of upcoming events over the next 30 days which summarizes each event.

I would like to create a link  provided with each event summary on the above page to another page that would show more details for a specific single event.

I cannot seem to write the code that will successfully take the eventId and query the Google Calendar API to retrieve the resources for that single event.

I apologize in advance as I am trying to learn Javascript as I go so I suspect this is something rather simple that I'm stuck on.

I am of the belief that in the makeApiCall() function I would desire to change the lines that start with:

var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({

to:

gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.get({
            'calendarId' : userEmail,
            'eventId': eventIDstr});

I can get a valid answer when using Google's APIs Explorer pages so I know I have the correct Calendar and Event IDs.  Just cannot seem to apply that to the correct javascript to get the results I am looking for.

I have searched high and low for samples of javascript that will retrieve a single Event's data from Google Calendar using v3 of their API and have come up with nothing useful.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right path. Use [`Events:get`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get). Events provides different flavors of [event resources](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations).

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
```

If successful, method returns an [event resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) in the response body.

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;

// ...

// Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
.setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

// Retrieve an event
Event event = service.events().get('primary', "eventId").execute();

System.out.println(event.getSummary());
```

You can use [`singleEvents=true`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#parameters) parameter in the list request to avoid the second call. This will ask the server to do the recurring [event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/pagination) expansion for you right away.